# Literally causing a StackOverflowError - Tiles 3

Tags: jsp, el, tiles, tiles-3

Migrating from the Struts 1.3/Tiles 1.x combo to the Struts 2/Tiles 3.
But this is really a Tiles question

Previously there was support for a bean declaration within the definition to support functionality as menu items, Tiles 3 have apparently gone away with that. So I've converted this:

```
    <definition name=".selectPatient.menu" path="/WEB-INF/templates/menu.jsp">
        <putList name="items">
            <bean classtype="org.a.m.s.jsp.MenuItem">
                <set-property property="id" value="menubar_register"/>        
                <set-property property="name" value="menubar_register"/>        
                <set-property property="title" value="Register"/>        
                <set-property property="onclick" value="registerPatient()"/>        
                <set-property property="text" value="Register"/>
                <set-property property="roles" value="BASIC,LEAD,SUPER"/>        
            </bean>
            <bean classtype="org.a.m.s.jsp.MenuItem">
                <set-property property="id" value="menubar_multitransaction"/>        
                <set-property property="name" value="menubar_multitransaction"/>        
                <set-property property="title" value="Post Multiple Transactions"/>        
                <set-property property="onclick" value="postMultiTransactions()"/>        
                <set-property property="text" value="Post Multiple Transactions"/>
                <set-property property="roles" value="BASIC,LEAD,SUPER"/>
            </bean>
        </putList>
    </definition>
```

and the corresponding menu.jsp page:

```
<logic:iterate id="item" name="items" type="org.a.m.s.jsp.MenuItem">
                <%if (UserRoles.userHasRole(request,item.getRoles())){%><td><table id="button_<bean:write name="item" property="id"/>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><img src="images/menu_button_round_edge_left2.gif"></td>
          <td style="border-top:1px white solid; border-bottom:1px white solid;">
                    <a name="<bean:write name="item" property="name"/>" id="<bean:write name="item" property="id"/>" accesskey="M" title="<bean:write name="item" property="title"/>" class="menuItem" href="#" isDisabled="false" onclick="if (this.isDisabled != 'true'&&isPageReady()) <bean:write name="item" property="onclick"/>;" 
                    onmouseover="if (this.isDisabled != 'true'&&isPageReady())document.getElementById('button_<bean:write name="item" property="id"/>').style.backgroundColor='#ffff99';" onmouseout="if (this.isDisabled != 'true'&&isPageReady())document.getElementById('button_<bean:write name="item" property="id"/>').style.backgroundColor='#000066';"><bean:write name="item" property="text"/></a></td>
          <td><img src="images/menu_button_round_edge_right2.gif" width="9" height="17"></td>
        </tr></table></td>
                <%}%>
</logic:iterate>
```

Migrated over to the

- definition:

```
    <definition name="defaultMenuComponent" template="/WEB-INF/templates/barbutton.jsp">
    </definition>

    <definition name="menubar_register" extends="defaultMenuComponent">
      <put-attribute name="id" value="menubar_register" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="name" value="menubar_register" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="title" value="Register" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="onclick" value="registerPatient()" cascade="true"/> 
      <put-attribute name="text" value="Register" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="roles" value="BASIC,LEAD,SUPER" cascade="true"/>   
    </definition>
    
    <definition name="menubar_multitransaction" extends="defaultMenuComponent">
      <put-attribute name="id" value="menubar_multitransaction" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="name" value="menubar_multitransaction" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="title" value="Post Multiple Transactions" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="onclick" value="postMultiTransactions()" cascade="true"/> 
      <put-attribute name="text" value="Post Multiple Transactions" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="roles" value="BASIC,LEAD,SUPER" cascade="true"/>   
    </definition>
    
    <definition name=".selectPatient.menu" template="/WEB-INF/templates/menu.jsp">
        <put-list-attribute name="items">
           <add-attribute value="menubar_register" type="definition"/>
           <add-attribute value="menubar_multitransaction" type="definition"/>   
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
```

- pushed all the construction logic into the barbutton.jsp :

```
<table id="button_<tiles:insertAttribute name="id" flush="true"/>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="images/menu_button_round_edge_left2.gif"></td>
<td style="border-top:1px white solid; border-bottom:1px white solid;">
<a name="<tiles:insertAttribute name="name" flush="true"/>" id="<tiles:insertAttribute name="id" flush="true"/>" accesskey="M" title="<tiles:insertAttribute name="title" flush="true"/>" class="menuItem" href="#" isDisabled="false" onclick="if (this.isDisabled != 'true'&&isPageReady()) <tiles:insertAttribute name="onclick" flush="true"/>;" onmouseover="if (this.isDisabled != 'true'&&isPageReady())document.getElementById('button_<tiles:insertAttribute name="id" flush="true"/>').style.backgroundColor='#ffff99';" onmouseout="if (this.isDisabled != 'true'&&isPageReady())document.getElementById('button_<tiles:insertAttribute name="id" flush="true"/>').style.backgroundColor='#000066';"><tiles:insertAttribute name="text" flush="true"/>
</a>
</td>
<td><img src="images/menu_button_round_edge_right2.gif" width="9" height="17"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

- and the menu.jsp gets changed as following:

```
<tilesx:useAttribute id="items" name="items" classname="java.util.List"/>

  <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1>
  <tr>       
     <c:forEach items="${items}" var="listItem">
       <td> 
       <tiles:insertDefinition name="${listItem}" flush="true"/> 
       </td>
     </c:forEach>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

And it does not work, getting the java.lang.StackOverflowError

tries various and different ways

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - renamed the menu definitions to .definition to differentiate from the included attributes.

```
    <definition name="defaultMenuComponent" template="/WEB-INF/templates/barbutton.jsp">
    </definition>

    <definition name=".menubar_register" extends="defaultMenuComponent">
      <put-attribute name="id" value="menubar_register" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="name" value="menubar_register" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="title" value="Register" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="onclick" value="registerPatient()" cascade="true"/> 
      <put-attribute name="text" value="Register" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="roles" value="BASIC,LEAD,SUPER" cascade="true"/>   
    </definition>
    
    <definition name=".menubar_multitransaction" extends="defaultMenuComponent">
      <put-attribute name="id" value="menubar_multitransaction" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="name" value="menubar_multitransaction" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="title" value="Post Multiple Transactions" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="onclick" value="postMultiTransactions()" cascade="true"/> 
      <put-attribute name="text" value="Post Multiple Transactions" cascade="true"/>
      <put-attribute name="roles" value="BASIC,LEAD,SUPER" cascade="true"/>   
    </definition>
    
    <definition name=".selectPatient.menu" template="/WEB-INF/templates/menu.jsp">
        <put-list-attribute name="items">
           <add-attribute value=".menubar_register" type="definition"/>
           <add-attribute value=".menubar_multitransaction" type="definition"/>   
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
```